# What's wrong with this program in C++ using an archive input?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I have the folowing code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int N;
    string s;
    char str[100];
    scanf("%d",&N);

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(str,100,stdin);
        s = str;
        cout << s << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code is save in an archive test.cpp.

Using the terminal on Linux Ubuntu for compile:

```
g++ -c hello.cpp
g++ -o hello hello.o
```

I have an archive test.in that will be the input:

```
5
God of War
Grand Theft Auto
The Smurfs
Final Fantasy
Call of Duty
```

Runing the command in terminal:

```
./test < test.in
```

The output will be:

```
rogerio@rogerio-Aspire-5741Z:~/Documentos$ ./teste < teste.in


God of War

Grand Theft Auto

The Smurfs

Final Fantasy

rogerio@rogerio-Aspire-5741Z:~/Documentos$
```

Because the line "Call of Duty" is jumped?

Comment: Compile with `g++ -Wall -g hello.cpp -o hello` and learn how to use the `gdb` debugger (e.g. start with `gdb hello`)

Comment: `test.cpp` Why then `hello.cpp` is compiled  ?

Comment: don't use `fflush(stdin);`

Comment: Using `fflush` on `stdin` is not defined.  Search StackOverflow for "fflush stdin".

Comment: @Thomas - I learned something new today.... Its amazing what shows up as undefined. I would have thought it would degenerate to a simple `nop`.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. Using 'scanf("%d\n",&N);' the five lines are read. hanks to all who helped!!

Answer (score 3):

The

```
scanf("%d",&N);
```

doesn't skip beyond end of line, therefore the first `fgets(str,100,stdin);` just reads the remainder of the line where `5` is given. Note the extra blank line in the output as you have posted it?